# Добавление настроек в панели администрирования django cms

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, cms, django-cms

Не работал еще с django cms, с админкой тем более, но знаю django. Вот сюда надо добавить еще пару настроек по типу AddOpt_1 (на картинках ниже). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вынести нужные поля в список list_display из твоей модели, подробнее по ссылке
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display